# c++20 module export/import

Tags: c++, module, visual-studio-2019, c++20

```cpp
// module A
export module A;

import <type_traits>;

namespace test
{
export{
    template<typename T, std::size_t N>
    class Foo;

    template<typename T>
    using Foo1 = Foo<T, 1>;

    template<typename T>
    struct is_Foo : std::false_type {};

    template<typename T, std::size_t N>
    struct is_Foo<Foo<T, N>> : std::true_type {};

    template<typename T>
    constexpr static bool is_Foo_v = is_Foo<T>::value;

    template<typename T>
    concept Foo_t = is_Foo_v<T>;
    }
}
```

```cpp
// module B
export module B;

export import module A;

namespace test
{
export{
    template<typename T, std::size_t>
    class Foo{ ... };
    }
}
```

```cpp
// module C
export module C;

export import module B;

namespace test
{
export{
    // (1)
    template<Foo_t T>
    constexpr void test_func(const T& t) { ... }
    }
}
```

```cpp
// test.cpp

import module C;
using namespace test;

constexpr void test_foo()
{
    // (2)
    constexpr Foo1 f1{1, 2, 3};
    // (3)
    test_func(f1);
    // (4)
    constexpr Foo1 f2{4, 5, 6};
}
```

(1): concept `Foo_t` works well here

(2): use `undefined class test::Foo<int, 1>`

Although the compiler outputs the use of undefined classes, the IDE can still prompt us using `Foo1<int> = Foo<int, 1>;`

(3): the compiler has no output for this line, and the IDE has not reported an error (marked in red)

(4): same as (2)

Note: The code has all been tested, and there are absolutely no syntax errors (if you do not compile into a module but use hpp, the code runs normally)

Someone may notice that module import has order requirements, which I have also tested and cannot solve the problem.

In file test.cpp, even if I import all the modules again, the problem couldn't be solved. And the error is still using the `undefined class test::Foo<int, 1>`

```cpp
// test.cpp
import module A;
import module B;
import module C;

// not work
```

The summary is:

1. Why does the symbol export fail?
2. What's more puzzling is why the IDE can find the symbols we use (although the `jump to definition` can't be used to jump over), but the compiler can't find it?

How to solve this problem?

============================================

After various attempts, I seem to have solved the above problems(I combine multiple modules into one module and divide the original content into multiple sub-modules), but now there are new problems.

```cpp
// module Foo
export module Foo;

export{ 
    template<typename T> struct Foo_trait : std::false_type 
    { 
        constexpr static auto size = 1; 
    }
    constexpr auto a_func_base_on_specialization_type_Foo_trait(...) 
    { 
        ... 
    }
}

// module Bar
export module Bar;

import module Foo;

export
{
    template<typename T, std::size_t N>
    class Baz;

    template<typename T, std::size_t N>
    struct Foo_trait<Baz<T, N>> : std::true_type { 
        constexpr static auto size = N; 
    }
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
class Baz { 
    constexpr Baz(something) : 
    data(a_func_base_on_specialization_type_Foo_trait(something)) {} 
}
```

I found that I cannot use `a_func_base_on_specialization_type_Foo_trait` to construct the class Baz, because the size is still `1` instead of `N`

============================================

I seem to have found the cause of the above problem

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/c20-modules-fail-to-pick-up-template-specializatio/1189551

Comment: I noticed that even if I don’t use an alias(Foo1) but use Foo directly, the same error is reported.

Answer (score 3):

You can’t declare `test::Foo` in one module (`A`) and define it in **another** module (`B`).  The standard says that it’s ill-formed, no diagnostic required; based on the preferences of its implementors, MSVC may interpret them as two different templates (as if they were named `__A::test::Foo` and `__B::test::Foo`), but then you’ll obviously have **ambiguities** trying to use one when both are available.

Comment: But why put it in the header file (hpp) and it will work properly? Maybe I misunderstood, I thought as long as there is a complete definition of the class (Foo) where the alias (Foo1) is used.

Comment: And maybe you noticed that I added below the question that even if the class name is used, it still reports an error.

Comment: @Life4gal: If you use headers, they are the same class template (although you could perhaps encounter an ODR violation or a point-of-instantiation issue).